# The simplest update statement is failing near ' '?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ' '.
```

I get the above error on this:

```
update activity
set scheduledforuseridy=557
  where datecompleted is null 
  and dateexpired is null 
  and scheduledforuseridy in (719,745,402) 
  and communityidy=4
```

What am I doing wrong? What does this error mean?

Comment: Any triggers on the table?

Comment: How are you running the query? The `go` command is not SQL, it only works in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: @Guffa thank you got rid of it for clarity

Comment: @MartinSmith there are no triggers

Comment: Are you running it in management studio?

Comment: @MartinSmith yes indeed i am

Comment: Sometimes weird errors like that can be caused if the text contains some non printed characters. What if you type the whole query out again from scratch in a new query window?

Comment: @MartinSmith sweeeeeeeeeeet that worked!!! the craziest thing is i did a TRIM() in excel for each line PLUS i manually removed and created all the spaces in the original query AND THAT STILL DID NOT WORK....until i followed your advice (however i did it in the same connection, not in a new window)

Comment: I have seem tab characters cause this kind of error

Answer (score -1):

There is no ' ' in you your update statement, that means, you some trigger is getting fired once you are updating the table activity. You can check if the triggers are present on the table by running the below query

```
select O.name as TableName,T.name as triggerName
from sys.triggers T
JOIN sys.objects O
ON T.object_id = O.object_id
and O.name = 'activity'
```